# How do I avoid rendering a component when another component in a similar path has already rendered when using URL params in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create RESTful routes for my application, but I'm having problems when it comes to routes with URL params.

Here are the routes that I want to have:

```
/accounts
/accounts/new
/accounts/edit
/accounts/:id
```

These is what my router looks like:

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/accounts" component={AccountsList} />
  <Route exact path="/accounts/new" component={AccountCreate} />
  <Route exact path="/accounts/edit" component={AccountUpdate} />
  <Route exact path="/accounts/:id" component={AccountDetail} />
</Router>
```

`/accounts` works fine, but when I go to `/accounts/new` or `/accounts/edit`, it also renders `AccountDetail` which is supposed to be located at `/accounts/:id`.

For the record, that I get that this is the correct behavior since `/accounts/:id` technically matches `/accounts/new` and `/accounts/edit`.

My question is if there's a way to make `:id` match with a specific pattern only (numbers only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [< Switch>](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) component of reactRouter.

> Renders the first child < Route> or < Redirect> that matches the
>   location.

I think it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for! Looks like I haven't gone through the documentation well enough. Thanks!